# Location of @classmethod

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.7

Where is the source code for the decorator classmethod located in the python source code.  Specifically I am having trouble finding the exact file it's defined in version 2.7.2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am not answering what you asked - but the code below shows what could be a decorator equivalent to `classmethod`, written in Pure Python - since the one in the source code is in C, inside [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ceb4b8d3ad48101e67da8fb8f581d3377863bfa/Objects/funcobject.c#L835) as Mishna puts in his answer (link updated for cPython development branch on GitHub).

So, the idea of class methods is to use the "descriptor" mechanism, as described in [Python's data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) - and make it so that the `__get__` method does return a function object that when called, will call the original method with the first argument pre-filled:

```
class myclassmethod(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return lambda *args, **kw: self.method(cls, *args, **kw)
```

And on Python console:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     @myclassmethod
...     def method(cls):
...         print cls
... 
>>> 
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.method()
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>>
```

*** EDIT - Update ***

The O.P. further asked "If I wanted the decorator to also accept a parameter what would be the proper format for init? " -

In that case it is not only `__init__` which has to be changed - a decorator that accepts configuration parameters is actually called in "two stages" - the first one annotate the parameters, and returns a callable - the second call accepts only the function which will actually be decorated.

There are a few ways to do it - but I think the most straightforward is to have a function that returns the class above, like in:

```
def myclasmethod(par1, par2, ...):
    class _myclassmethod(object):
        def __init__(self, method):
            self.method = method
        def __get__(self, instance, cls):
            # make use of par1, par2,... variables here at will
            return lambda *args, **kw: self.method(cls, *args, **kw)
    return _myclassmethod
```

Comment: If I wanted the decorator to also accept a parameter what would be the proper format for init?

Comment: can \_\_call\_\_ be used instead of \_\_get\_\_?

Comment: ok, after reading a bit about descriptors it makes sense now :)

Comment: Many examples of decorators use functions. What is the difference in making it a class, here ?

Comment: What was your conclusion, @DiogoNeves ? Could or couldn't you use `__call__` instead of `__get__` and why ?

Answer (score 15):

```
tar -zxf Python-2.7.2.tgz
vim Python-2.7.2/Objects/funcobject.c

...
589 /* Class method object */
590 
591 /* A class method receives the class as implicit first argument,
592    just like an instance method receives the instance.
593    To declare a class method, use this idiom:
594 
595      class C:
596      def f(cls, arg1, arg2, ...): ...
597      f = classmethod(f)
598 
599    It can be called either on the class (e.g. C.f()) or on an instance
600    (e.g. C().f()); the instance is ignored except for its class.
601    If a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class
602    object is passed as the implied first argument.
603 
604    Class methods are different than C++ or Java static methods.
605    If you want those, see static methods below.
606 */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.1.3...\stdlib\builtins.pyi:

```
class staticmethod(Generic[_R]):
__func__: Callable[..., _R]
__isabstractmethod__: bool
def __init__(self: staticmethod[_R], __f: Callable[..., _R]) -> None: ...
def __get__(self, __obj: _T, __type: type[_T] | None = ...) -> Callable[..., _R]: ...
if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    __name__: str
    __qualname__: str
    __wrapped__: Callable[..., _R]
    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _R: ...

class classmethod(Generic[_R]):
__func__: Callable[..., _R]
__isabstractmethod__: bool
def __init__(self: classmethod[_R], __f: Callable[..., _R]) -> None: ...
def __get__(self, __obj: _T, __type: type[_T] | None = ...) -> Callable[..., _R]: ...
if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    __name__: str
    __qualname__: str
    __wrapped__: Callable[..., _R]
```