# Python - why can I call a class method with an instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, class-method

New to Python and having done some reading, I'm making some methods in my custom class class methods rather than instance methods.

So I tested my code but I hadn't changed some of the method calls to call the method in the class rather than the instance, but they still worked:

```
class myClass:
   @classmethod:
   def foo(cls):
      print 'Class method foo called with %s.'%(cls)

   def bar(self):
      print 'Instance method bar called with %s.'%(self)

myClass.foo()
thing = myClass()
thing.foo()
thing.bar()
```

This produces:

```
class method foo called with __main__.myClass.
class method foo called with __main__.myClass.
instance method bar called with <__main__.myClass instance at 0x389ba4>.
```

So what I'm wondering is why I can call a class method (foo) on an instance (thing.foo), (although it's the class that gets passed to the method)? It kind of makes sense, as 'thing' is a 'myClass', but I was expecting Python to give an error saying something along the lines of 'foo is a class method and can't be called on an instance'.

Is this just an expected consequence of inheritance with the 'thing' object inheriting the foo method from its superclass?

If I try to call the instance method via the class:

```
myClass.bar()
```

then I get:

```
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with myClass instance...
```

which makes perfect sense.

Comment: In Python, methods are not called *on* something. `thing.foo` is not a method call, it is an attribute access,  It is basically the same thing as `getattr(thing, "foo")`.

Comment: @Alexey Surely 'foo` is a method and `thing.foo()` is calling the `foo` method of the object `thing`? Isn't an attribute Python's terminology for what other languages refer to as a variable or property?

Comment: I think that "`(thing.foo)()` is calling the `foo` method of the object `thing`" (parentheses for clarity) is a metaphor for "`(thing.foo)()` is calling the callable object `thing.foo`", that is it.  AFAIU, this object is created dynamically when `getattr(thing, "foo")` is called, and of course it has a reference to `thing` object.

Comment: Note the difference between object "attributes" that are defined by its class and the attributes that are "stored" in the object itself.  Because if you have a function (or any object/value) `bar`, you can write `thing.foo = bar`, and then call it `thing.foo()` if `bar` was callable. In this case the object returned by `thing.foo` is actually stored in the dictionary `thing.__dict__`, and not generated dynamically, as, i suppose, is the case with "instance methods" defined as a part of class definition.

Comment: "Isn't an attribute Python's terminology for what other languages refer to as a variable or property?" -- AFAIU from my experiments with Python, Python plays its tricks by allowing [arbitrary customisation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) of attribut getters and setters.  The "magic" happens when you write or read an attribute.  Attributes are not just record fields: using them can trigger arbitrary code.

Comment: @SteveIves See my answer. The `class` statement defines two functions: one is bound to the class attribute `bar`, the other is wrapped in an instance of `classmethod` and bound to the class attribute `foo`. `thing.foo`, then, is an attribute lookup whose *result* is a callable object, not the original function or the `classmethod` instance itself but an instance of the `method` class, produced by the descriptor protocol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can call it on an instance because `@classmethod` is a [decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) (it takes a function as an argument and returns a new function).

Here is some relavent information from the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)

> It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance
>   (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class. If a
>   class method is called for a derived class, the derived class object
>   is passed as the implied first argument.

There's also quite a good SO discussion on `@classmethod` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247625/location-of-classmethod).

Comment: Thank you - I did various searches for inheritance, classmethods etc, but as you can imagine, the results were overwhelming. I would have been quite happy to simply accept that it works, but as an assembler programmer, I like to know how things work under the covers.

Comment: "You can call it on an instance because @classmethod is a decorator" -- i do not follow this logic.

Comment: @Alexey do you know what a decorator is?

Comment: Yes. But i believe i can make a decorator such that the decorated function will produce a class attribute that will raise errors if called as an instance method (in fact, which will not be callable at all).  For example: `def decor(f): return 42`.

Comment: Technically, `classmethod` is a type; calling it returns an instance of `classmethod`, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a quick overview of the descriptor protocol. If a class defines a `__get__` method, an instance of that class is a descriptor. Accessing a descriptor as the attribute of another object produces the return value of the `__get__` method, not the descriptor itself.

A `function` is a descriptor; this is how instance methods are implemented. Given

```
class myClass:
    @classmethod:
    def foo(cls):
        print('Class method foo called with %s.' % (cls,))

    def bar(self):
        print 'Instance method bar called with %s.'%(self)

c = myClass()
```

the expression `c.bar` is equivalent to

```
myClass.__dict__['bar'].__get__(c, myClass)
```

while the expression `myClass.bar` is equivalent to the expression

```
myClass.__dict__['bar'].__get__(None, myClass)
```

Note the only difference is in the object passed as the first argument to `__get__`.  The former returns a new `method` object, which when called passes `c` and its own arguments on to the function `bar`. This is why `c.bar()` and `C.bar(c)` are equivalent. The latter simply returns the function `bar` itself.

`classmethod` is a type that provides a *different* implementation of `__get__`. This means that `c.foo()` and `myClass.foo()` call `__get__` as before:

```
# c.foo
myClass.__dict__['foo'].__get__(c, myClass)

# myClass.foo
myClass.__dict__['foo'].__get__(None, myClass)
```

Now, however, *both* calls return the same `method` object, and this `method` object, when called, passes `myClass` as the first argument to the original `function` object. That is, `c.foo()` is equivalent to `myClass.foo()`, which
is equivalent to `x(myClass)` (where `x` is the original function defined before the decoration bound the name `foo` to an instance of `classmethod`).

Comment: A good complement to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9248432/10133797), where seeing `__get__` implemented helps complete the picture. Though I'm unsure why `cls` is being passed to `self.method` instead of `instance`, and why `instance` is unused

Comment: That's by design. A class method always receives a class as its first argument. If you invoke it from a class, you get the class. If you invoke it from an instance of the class, you get that instance's type.