# how come python allows sending class method to instance?

Tags: python, class, class-method

Shouldn't the following snippet raise an error? Just can't understand how this is permitted (or why). Thanks in advance :)

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi(self):
        print ("Hi!, I'm  " + self.name)

    @classmethod
    def gral_hi(cls):
        print('Hi!')

a = A('ann')
a.say_hi()
A.gral_hi() # sends class method to class
a.gral_hi() # sends class method to instance
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: See [Python - why can I call a class method with an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190061/python-why-can-i-call-a-class-method-with-an-instance)

Comment: This is one reason for having the `classmethod` type: so that you can invoke a method that receives a class as its argument, whether you invoke the argument with the class or an instance of the class.